# Add Migration gives "Unable to resolve project from ..."

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

Using EF7 on an ASP.NET 5 project I tried to add a migration typing the following on VS Package Manager Console:

```
dnx ef migrations add InitialDatabaseSetup
```

And I got the error:

```
Unable to resolve project from C:\Projects\ASPNET5DEMO
```

The project is inside C:\Projects\ASPNET5DEMO\src\aspnet5demo.web

If use Developer Command Prompt to navigate to that path and then run the command then everything works fine ...

Is there a way to use Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package Manager Console is just a powershell host.  If you type `pwd` you'll see that it's current directory is `C:\Projects\ASPNET5DEMO`.

Then you can access the relevant command by using;

```
dnx -p src\aspnet5demo.web ef migrations add InitialDatabaseSetup
```

or

```
cd src\aspnet5demo.web
dnx ef migrations add InitialDatabaseSetup
```

Comment: Good answer. Would change the dnx with dotnet though in .netcore RC2

Comment: @AfshinTeymoori could do, but i'm not using RC2 yet - is `dotnet` a direct replacement in the commands above?  ie; do they still work?